# Malware application trying to override system application

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, malware, ads

My device (Symphony W69Q; running Android 4.4.2) recently encountered an annoying problem. It's UI began to turn off & restart continuously. I also some unwanted apps running in background and showing me annoying ads. As I haven't downloaded these apps & don't know how did they come.
So, I checked my In Settings > Apps > Downloaded and found 2 unknown apps & deleted them. But somehow they appeared again. It's good to say that my device is rooted. I then went to system/app folder and found those 2 of them:
1.apk name: com.swiping.whale.apk
package name: com.android.SYSTEMUI
.
.
.
2.apk name: com.system.cap.qs.iupdater.apk
package name: com.android.updater
.

.
I tried to delete them but failed though I'm rooted. I faced a new problem at night when the original systemUI & Android updater stop working. I think those unwanted culprit apps are trying to override the original system apps because their package name matches the system apps.
I can't figure out the problem. Is this a new kind of advertisement idea to force user to download apps until it damages their device?
Oh yes, after this prob, my 3G data is draining quickly. I downloaded an app named "anWriter" yesterday though faced the prob today. My device is rooted for several months.

Comment: What makes you suspect those two APK files in particular?